# Confirmed deleted object in rails backend is coming up as 'undefined' in rails front end?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-redux, ruby-on-rails-5

I deleted an object, I saw that that rails server gave me a `Completed 200 OK` after deletion and I checked to see if `Objects.count.all` did indeed decrease after an object was deleted.

HOWEVER, the problem is that my React project is breaking because, when I iterate through Objects to display all the objects in an index, the deleted objects are coming up as `undefined`.

I have reset my server and my computer. It did not fix the issue.

Any ideas as to what the problem and solution are?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like you are somewhere in your (rails) code still referencing said deleted objects, so they are nil in ruby, then references as undefined y JS

Comment: Yes. I just realized the problem. Every photo is associated to an album, but that association is made through a join stable that is stores a photo id and an album id. When I load an album, it uses the join stable to find photos that match the album id. When I delete the photo, I am not deleting the joins.